# which value of Azimuth, Elevation and SNR to process with GPGSV NMEA message?

Tags: gps, elevation, nmea, azimuth

I was working on the parsing logic for GPS. I'm trying to parse the GPGSV message, I was able to find 12 satellite's information of 4 parameters like PRN, SNR, Azimuth and Elevation. But I'm not sure which one of these 12 values would be the valid information to send out. And I'm not sure, whether if I calculate the average of these values, would make it valid to use it.

Answer (score 0):

They are all valid. If you wish to summarise the information then I would suggest the number of satellites being reported and the average SNR.